# Select a Random Database Row WHERE ID=a random value created by PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

If I have a PHP function that generates a random number, is it possible to pass that variable into the sql statement in the WHERE clause? I'm using CodeIgniter, so this is my code using its syntax.

```
$random = rand(1, 572);
$result = $this->db->query( ' SELECT part1, part2, _id FROM `questions` WHERE `_id` >= '$random' LIMIT 0,1 ');
```

Is this even possible to do?

EDIT: The reason I want the php to execute the random number is because I need to call it multiple times throughout my pages, and it needs to do another call to another database using a sql query

Comment: How do you know that random num exists?

Comment: Don't let people persuade you to use a different solution, you're headed in the right direction anyway. http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/  ...otherwise, you just need to learn to concatenate strings (in PHP, use the period)

Comment: Because I know I have 572 rows right now. In the future that will probably grow, so what would be the best way to pass into that rand() function the max amount of rows in my table?

Comment: @TehShrike: If the solution is better than my current, then I personally will let others persuade me into using that :) Of course they'd have to let me understand first why their solution is better

Comment: @Rolando: your solution is correct, though your suggestion (ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) is misinformed - you should check out that last post I linked! It's quite good.

Comment: @TehShrike: Wow! I didn't know that! Should have posted your own answer though too. That would have helped the OP better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you concatenate the variable with the string:

```
$query = "SELECT 
            part1, 
            part2, 
            _id 
          FROM
            questions
          WHERE _id >= " . $random . " LIMIT 0,1";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

But if what you want is to select a random row, then you might want this query

```
 SELECT part1, part2, _id FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT**

I understand that `_id` will be random, but you are specifying the `min` and `max` for `rand()`, right? So you'd have to change it whenever you insert a new row, or you'd have to use two queries if you want to make sure `rand()` does not return a value too high. By using `ORDER BY RAND()` you are free from both problems. You simply have to get the value of `_id` that was returned from the query.

Comment: Sorry, read my edit. I need to use that same number for a different call as well to a different database

Comment: @Bert why not use the id selected in the query for that?

Comment: This is exactly it. I forgot to concatenate it. I will accept your answer as best ASAP, stackoverflow is giving me a waiting period before I can select it as best.

Comment: But you'd have to harcode the maximum value of `rand()` every time you insert something to the database. If you simply want to store the ID, then get it from the result. You are returning `_id` from the query anyways.

Comment: @Rolando, wouldn't I need to run a COUNT() query to get the amount of rows in my table? The _id I'm getting is just a random one, not my maximum amount.

Comment: Yes, but you execute the `rand()` before you execute the query. So if you want to use `COUNT()` you'd have to use 2 queries now. I understand that `_id` will be random but you are specifying the `min` and `max` for `rand()`, right? So you'd have to change it whenever you insert a new row, or you'd have to use two queries if you want to make sure `rand()` does not return a value too high. By using `ORDER BY RAND()` you are free from both problems. You simply have to get the value of `_id` that was returned from the query.

Comment: @Rolando, that totally helps out even more. That's what I'll be doing instead. I can take that _id, put it to a variable and call it again throughout the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a mater of using double quotes instead of single quotes on the outside of your string.

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT part1, part2, _id FROM `questions` WHERE `_id` >= '$random' LIMIT 0,1 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT part1, part2, _id FROM questions WHERE _id >= '".$random."' LIMIT 0,1 ");
```